# How to implement ILU precondioner in scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra

For the iterative solvers in the `scipy.sparse.linalg` such as `bicg`, `gmres`, etc, there is an option to add the precondioner for the matrix `A`. However, the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.bicg.html) is not very clear about what I should give as the preconditioner. If I use `ilu = sp.sparse.linalg.spilu(A)`, `ilu` is not any matrices but an object that encompasses many things.

Someone asked about a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46876951/sparse-matrix-solver-with-preconditioner) for Python 2.7, but I doesn't work for me (Python 3.7, scipy version 1.1.0)

So my question is how to incorporate incomplete LU preconditioner for those iterative algorithms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a preconditioner, [bicg](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.bicg.html) or [gmres](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.gmres.html) accept

- sparse matrix
- dense matrix
- linear operator

In your case, the preconditioner comes from a factorization, thus it has to be passed as a linear operator.

Thus, you may want to explicitly define a linear operator from the ILU factorization you obtained via `spilu`. Something along the lines:

```
sA_iLU = sparse.linalg.spilu(sA)
M = sparse.linalg.LinearOperator((nrows,ncols), sA_iLU.solve)
```

Here, `sA` is a sparse matrix in a CSC format, and `M` will now be the preconditioner linear operator that you will supply to the iterative solver.

---

A complete example [based on the question you mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37092195/2452869):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
from scipy.sparse import linalg

A = np.array([[ 0.4445,  0.4444, -0.2222],
              [ 0.4444,  0.4445, -0.2222],
              [-0.2222, -0.2222,  0.1112]])
sA = sparse.csc_matrix(A)

b = np.array([[ 0.6667], 
              [ 0.6667], 
              [-0.3332]])

sA_iLU = sparse.linalg.spilu(sA)
M = sparse.linalg.LinearOperator((3,3), sA_iLU.solve)

x = sparse.linalg.gmres(A,b,M=M)

print(x)
```

Notes:

- I am actually using a dense matrix as an example, while it would make more sense to start from a representative sparse matrix in your case.
- size of the linear operator `M` is hardcoded.
- ILU has not been configured anyhow, but with the defaults.
- this is pretty much what has been suggested [in the comments to that aforementioned answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36995091/how-to-implement-ilu-preconditioner-for-gmres-in-python-2-7#comment89817243_37092195), however, I had to do small tweaks to make it Python3-compatible.

Comment: It works for `bicgstab` and `gmres`, but when I use it for `bicg` it gives `NotImplementedError: rmatvec is not defined`, and when I use it for `minres` it gives `ValueError: indefinite preconditioner`. Any idea what happens?