# What algorithm does the scipy.sparse.linalg.spilu(A).solve() function use?

Tags: python, scipy

Consider the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse.linalg

# Setup
A = scipy.sparse.csc_matrix([[1, -3], [-1, 4]])
b = np.array([1, 0])

spilu = scipy.sparse.linalg.spilu(A)  # Find ILU decomposition
x = spilu.solve(b)  # Use an iterative method to solve Ax = b ?
```

This results in `x` being the solution to `Ax = b`.

It is my understanding that `scipy.sparse.linalg.spilu(A)` calculates an incomplete LU decomposition of A.

My question is: what algorithm exactly does `spilu.solve(b)` use to solve for `Ax = b`?

I would expect it to use some iterative method such as the conjugate gradient method because that seems to be the normal way to use an incomplete LU decomposition. However, I have been unable to find documentation supporting or disagreeing with this. Furthermore, I'm confused because I see some people use `LinearOperator` and `scipy.sparse.linalg.cg`/`scipy.sparse.linalg.cg` in conjunction with `scipy.sparse.linalg.spilu(A)`, which would seem foolish if my hypothesis is correct ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58895934/how-to-implement-ilu-precondioner-in-scipy)).

Comment: You're really digging deep, but if you want to pursue this - you can look at the source code. The module you use calls:
      return _superlu.gstrf(N, A.nnz, A.data, A.indices, A.indptr, ilu=True, options=_options)
gstrf is a method from the superlu package (it's not in python) - you can try looking how they calculate ILU in their docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Docs](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.spilu.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.spilu) say:

> This function uses the SuperLU library.

[Code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/8ab8a383c418f4caee155b9e0ce57fde6ca4aadd/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/linsolve.py#L418) passes through:

```
return _superlu.gstrf(N, A.nnz, A.data, A.indices, A.indptr,
                      csc_construct_func=csc_construct_func,
                      ilu=True, options=_options)
```

[which is](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/5bd4bfce8b8a84ef63f9b67b20429f5ef6aace72/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/_superlumodule.c#L270) just a SuperLU wrapper:

```
static char gstrf_doc[] = "gstrf(A, ...)\n\
\n\
performs a factorization of the sparse matrix A=*(N,nnz,nzvals,rowind,colptr) and \n\
returns a factored_lu object.\n\
\n\
arguments\n\
---------\n\
\n\
Matrix to be factorized is represented as N,nnz,nzvals,rowind,colptr\n\
  as separate arguments.  This is compressed sparse column representation.\n\
\n\
N         number of rows and columns \n\
nnz       number of non-zero elements\n\
nzvals    non-zero values \n\
rowind    row-index for this column (same size as nzvals)\n\
colptr    index into rowind for first non-zero value in this column\n\
          size is (N+1).  Last value should be nnz. \n\
\n\
additional keyword arguments:\n\
-----------------------------\n\
options             specifies additional options for SuperLU\n\
                    (same keys and values as in superlu_options_t C structure,\n\
                    and additionally 'Relax' and 'PanelSize')\n\
\n\
ilu                 whether to perform an incomplete LU decomposition\n\
                    (default: false)\n\
";
```

**look at the last argument -> ilu!**

[splu](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/8ab8a383c418f4caee155b9e0ce57fde6ca4aadd/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/linsolve.py#L327) looks like:

```
return _superlu.gstrf(N, A.nnz, A.data, A.indices, A.indptr,
                      csc_construct_func=csc_construct_func,
                      ilu=False, options=_options)
```

which indicates that the whole complete vs. incomplete logic is passed to SuperLU.

Now let's look into [SuperLU's manual](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.366.2886&rep=rep1&type=pdf):

> 2.7 Incomplete LU factorization (ILU) preconditioner
>
> Starting from SuperLU version 4.0, we provide the ILU routines to be used as preconditioners
>       for iterative solvers. Our ILU method can be considered to be a variant of the ILUTP method
>       originally proposed by Saad [31], which combines a dual dropping strategy with numerical pivoting
>       (“T” stands for threshold, and “P” stands for pivoting).

The reference [31] is:

> Saad, Yousef. "ILUT: A dual threshold incomplete LU factorization." Numerical linear algebra with applications 1.4 (1994): 387-402.

**This looks like a DIRECT method to me** ([Eigen does use it too](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SuperILU.html)), but i think you will be able to lookup what you need to know.

Answer (score 1):

This solve method *approximately solves* `Ax=b`by using an incomplete factorization of `A`. That is why you see it used as a preconditioner in those iterative methods. The solve method is a classical sparse forward/back substitution algorithm using the incomplete factors, but since they are incomplete it is unlikely to give an exact result.

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto sascha's answer:

The `solve` function of the object returned by `_superlu.gstrf` can be found in [scipy/sparse/linalg/_dsolve/_superluobject.c](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/2af8d018f926995e25f0b1e0c7983f94680531e3/scipy/sparse/linalg/_dsolve/_superluobject.c#L21). The main part is a call to [`gstrs`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/2af8d018f926995e25f0b1e0c7983f94680531e3/scipy/sparse/linalg/_dsolve/_superluobject.c#L85) (notice the that it is `gstrs` instead of `gstrf`):

```
static PyObject *SuperLU_solve(SuperLUObject * self, PyObject * args,
                               PyObject * kwds)
{
...
    gstrs(self->type,
          trans, &self->L, &self->U, self->perm_c, self->perm_r,
          (SuperMatrix *)&B, (SuperLUStat_t *)&stat, (int *)&info);
...
}
```

Looking into the [documentation of SuperLU](https://portal.nersc.gov/project/sparse/superlu/superlu_code_html/dgstrs_8c.html):

```
DGSTRS solves a system of linear equations A*X=B or A'*X=B
with A sparse and B dense, using the LU factorization computed by
DGSTRF.
```

So what the Python code is basically doing is calling `*gstrf` to calculate the LU factorization, and then give that to `*gstrs` to calculate the solution of a system.

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/erdc/superlu/blob/51cd6c3f05d4701fa7163aee4e356e11ac81153e/SRC/dgstrs.c#L90) of `dgstrs` it looks like it is just using the LU factorization, no matter if it is an incomplete one or not (also there is no argument that would allow specifying that), so it will just give you an approximate solution with an incomplete factorization.